# Infdig in Custom groupBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i recently needed some kinda customized repeater, which group data by their key, but not simply group them all together, so i read several references and things,... and at last i come up to copy 
groupBy from this article which he seem to complete it at best, ... 
http://sobrepere.com/blog/2014/10/14/creating-groupby-filter-angularjs/
And then i customized so it become like this:

the things my group by do... is:

Group Data Together Until It Reach Differences.
but the matter is that though it work, it still generate infdig, i know it's because the digest done call other one, but what i don't know is how to solve it in very easy and understandable manner, as i'm new to JavaScript...

```
        app.filter('groupBy', function () {
            var results = {};
            return function (data, key) { //Data => My Objects Array - Key => Name Of Filtered Property
                if (!(data && key)) return;
                var result;
                if (!this.$id) {
                    result = {};
                } else {
                    var scopeId = this.$id;
                    if (!results[scopeId]) {
                        results[scopeId] = {};
                        this.$on("$destroy", function () {
                            delete results[scopeId];
                        });
                    }
                    result = results[scopeId];
                }

                for (var groupKey in result)
                    result[groupKey].splice(0, result[groupKey].length);

                var grpKey = -1; //GroupKey
                var lastUserId;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (!result[grpKey] || lastUserId && lastUserId != data[i][key]) // Ex.: result[data[0]["UserId"]]{ => return UserId
                        result[++ grpKey] = [];

                    result[grpKey].push(data[i]);
                    lastUserId = data[i][key];
                }

                var keys = Object.keys(result);
                for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                    if (result[keys[k]].length === 0)
                        delete result[keys[k]];
                }
                return result;
        };
             });
```

Comment: can you make a plunkr witn your code

Comment: Hi pls find this url, its working perfectly... http://plnkr.co/edit/8jB4wSRtKfVmEsTGZtfV?p=preview

Comment: in this what you need to do exactly

Comment: no infdig Infinite $digest Loop is shown in console of your plunkr

Answer (score 0):

In this url is working perfectly...
             http://plnkr.co/edit/8jB4wSRtKfVmEsTGZtfV?p=preview

```
          app.filter('groupBy', function ($timeout) {
          return function (data, key) {
    if (!key) return data;
    var outputPropertyName = '__groupBy__' + key;
    if(!data[outputPropertyName]){
        var result = {};  
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            if (!result[data[i][key]])
                result[data[i][key]]=[];
            result[data[i][key]].push(data[i]);
        }
        Object.defineProperty(result, 'length', {enumerable: false, value: Object.keys(result).length});
        Object.defineProperty(data, outputPropertyName, {enumerable:false, configurable:true, writable: false, value:result});
        $timeout(function(){delete data[outputPropertyName];},0,false);
        }
     return data[outputPropertyName];
            };
    });
```